# toggle button label and functionality using ToggleButton

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chG5K/) that I am working on, I referred [this example](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/ToggleButton.html#programmatic-example).

```
require(["dijit/form/ToggleButton", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ToggleButton){
    new ToggleButton({
        showLabel: true,
        checked: false,
        onChange: function(val){
            this.set('label',val);
            alert("function 1");
        },
        label: "Start"
    }, "programmatic");
});
```

Here, I did not understand where `val` is passed from.

1. How can I toggle the label as "Start" and "Stop"?
2. How can I do `alert('function 1')` when `Start` button is clicked and
       `alert('function 2')` when `Stop` is clicked? I plan to have different functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onChange` event handler returns a boolean if the togglebutton is checked/toggled or not. So you could easily write an `if` like this:

```
onChange: function(val) {
    if (val) {
        this.set('label', 'Stop');
        alert('function 1');
    } else {
        this.set('label', 'Start');
        alert('function 2');
    }
}
```

If you want to seperate both in other functions you could override the `onChange` event handler each time, but I think it's easier if you just do something like this:

```
onChange: function(val) {
    if (val) {
        this.function1();
    } else {
        this.function2();
    }
},
function1: function() {
    this.set('label', 'Stop');   
    alert("function1");
},
function2: function() {
    this.set('label', 'Start');
    alert("function2");
},
```

I also updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/chG5K/1/).